# Anyone experienced using Workbox on Elastic Beanstalk? Not detecting

Tags: node.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, workbox

Workbox is working perfectly in local development. But when deployed to Elastic Beanstalk, EB is not able to register the service worker. Everything is working from Express view engine, webpack build files, etc. The only problem is that the Workbox is not detected.

Build flow is from Git, to Travis, then deploy to EB.

So far, tried everything. I even SSH to the EC2 instance to check if the build files are really there, existing. And all files are present.

Also, what I noticed is that the EC2 instance used by EB has a Node version of 8.16.0 but inside Elastic Beanstalk Configuration => Software, the Node version is 10.16.0 I don't which is being used really.

Comment: Is your build being served over HTTPS?

Comment: @GaryVernonGrubb it is not being served over HTTPS yet, but I think that won't hinder Workbox from installing. Cause on local development, it is being registered and working perfectly. Do you think I really need to serve HTTPS for EB to register Workbox sw.js?

Comment: Yes, I believe it needs HTTPS and the other minimum PWA requirements. You can quickly test HTTPS by creating a Cloudfront distribution. Cloudfront has an option to serve over HTTPs.

Comment: I just rechecked, it needs HTTPS. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case would be to ensure that the build is served over HTTPS.
A quick way to setup HTTPS on AWS / EC2 is using a Cloudfront distribution.
You may also test by using HTTPS via a S3 static website.

[Confirmation about the HTTPS requirement](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker)